# how to know when asynchronous search using MapKit is complete

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am using mapkit to allow a user to search for an address.  Pressing another button (the goButton) will ask them to confirm a formatted address populated using the results of their search, and also will send a command to search behind the scenes if the user entered text but did not actually search for the address before selecting goButton.  My problem is that because the search is completing asynchronously, the confirmation function is being called too soon.
Is there a way I can tell when the search is completed?  I tried putting a bool at the end of searchBarSearchButtonClicked and a while loop before calling confirmHostAddress that checked the value of the bool, but it did not detect a change.  Thanks for your help.

```
@IBAction func goButton(sender: UIButton) {

    //check and see if there is an address, if not, do search behind the scenes
    if (myAddress == nil)
    {
        if (mapSearch.text != "")
        {
            self.searchBarSearchButtonClicked(self.mapSearch)
            confirmHostAddress()
        }
        else
        {
            alertTextNeeded()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        confirmHostAddress()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your async search is in `confirmHostAddress()`? That function needs to have a callback block, which will (hopefully) be running on a background thread. Within that callback, use `dispatch_async()` to enqueue, onto the main queue, the UI change that you want.

Search button click (on main queue) triggers search (on background queue), and search completion triggers (on main queue) UI update.